# Sort row in array as easily as possible (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I have this table with 750 rows of infomation. Its extracted using php. However, in one of the rows I have this image popping up, the image src will either be 1.jpg or 0.jpg. This will chose between https://gyazo.com/81f37995cfb2fbeaec157716d06b3816 these two pictures.

So how can I possibly sort this row after what picture it displays and how to make the code as simple as possible to ensure that it wont take to long time/effort for the computer using the website ordering the line. (Using Javascipt of course)

So the code is supposed to order the rows over again to put for example the td's with <img src="0.jpg" /> in it gets placed first and then put the td's with <img src="1.jpg" /> at the end. To sort them.

Example code:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Checked or unchecked</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td><img src="1.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name2</td>
      <td><img src="0.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "sort this row"? Can you share the code that you already tried that isn't working?

Comment: I currently don't know a way to sort them after the img src code.

Comment: Add a data attribute to the row and sort by that.

Comment: @Fleischpfanzerl I think he means he wants to "filter by" ones that are checked or crossed. I'm speaking in excel UI terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
function sortCol(desc) {
  const tbl = document.querySelector("table>tbody");
  const rows = Array.from(tbl.rows).slice(1).sort((a, b) =>
    a.querySelector("img").src.localeCompare(b.querySelector("img").src)
  );
  if (desc) rows.reverse();
  rows.forEach(row => tbl.appendChild(row));
}
```

Call it with argument `true` when you want to have a descending sort order. If you have more than one table on your page, you need to qualify the selector at the start of the function to target the right table.